# Applying the block matrix inverse formula twice

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices

Suppose $Y$ is a symmetric block matrix with 4 blocks

$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} aX & bX \\ bX & cX \end{bmatrix} $$
where $a, b, c, d$ are constants, and $X$ is an invertible submatrix.

Using the [2x2 block matrix inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) formula,

$$Z := Y^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{ac-b^2}{c}X & \frac{-b(ac-b^2)}{c^2}X \\  \frac{-b(ac-b^2)}{c^2}X & \frac{ac-b^2}{a}X \end{bmatrix} $$

If I apply the 2x2 block matrix inverse formula again, I get

$$Z^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{c^3(ac-b^2)-ab^2(ac-b^2)}{c^4}X & \frac{c^3(ac-b^2)-ab^2(ac-b^2)-abc^3}{c^4} X \\  \frac{c^3(ac-b^2)-ab^2(ac-b^2)-abc^3}{c^4}X & \frac{c^4(ac-b^2)-ab^2(ac-b^2)}{ac^4}X \end{bmatrix} $$

However, shouldn't $Y = Z^{-1}$? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You're not done simplifying!

Comment: Shouldn't there be $X^{-1}$ somewhere inside $Y^{-1}$?

Comment: I checked the top left corner of your $Z$ and it seems upside-down. You have $\frac{ac-b^2}{c}X$ but it should be $\frac{c}{ac-b^2}X^{-1}$. I assume the others are similarly wrong. Also, you mention constants "$a,b,c,d$" but only use constants $a,b,c$. I think it's more instructive if you used $a,b,c,d$ instead of $a,b,c$ in your original matrix.

Comment: Since $Y=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}\otimes X$ (where the symbol $\otimes$ denotes [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)), it is invertible if and only if both $\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$ and $X$ are invertible, and $$Y^{-1}=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}^{-1}\otimes X^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\pmatrix{d&-b\\ -c&a}\otimes X^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\pmatrix{dX^{-1}&-bX^{-1}\\ -cX^{-1}&aX^{-1}}.$$ You don’t need any block matrix inversion formula.